# Upgrade i20 head lamps bulb

Tags: hyundai, bulbs

I would like to fit Zorbes H4 12V 60/55W Halogen Bulbs 6000K Xenon in Hyundai i20 car which has H4 60/55w bulb connector . But below are some dauds and would be pleased if you could kindly help me.

1. Being of the same specs with this particular car, can I used just by replacing  the factory fitted bulbs?
2. Do any extra wiring is necessary for the new bulb and should relay be compulsory for the bulbs to work in this car? 
   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the ratings of the new bulbs appear to be the same from what you state, then go ahead and fit them.

If the bulbs needed higher current then changing the supply would be necessary - checking relays, fuses etc

Comment: What about if they use less current (high efficiency, LED, etc)?